# Loop through List(of Items) with each one being asynced downloaded

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I have a list of object that i loop through, and in this loop i have an async webrequest that is getting a response from a site, according to the current object's data.

How can i wait for each async request to complete b4 going to the next object in the list?
Should i use application.doevents?

Comment: I think you should use synchronous webrequest since you wanted to process the list synchronously, no?

Comment: Yes, i want to go through the list 1 by 1. But i dont want to freeze the UI.. Because i also want to have a cancel button

Answer (score 0):

In you async callback, kick off the next request when the current one completes. At that point you can also check if the cancel button was pressed and cancel the request if it was.